# Make Visual Studio Code recognise module and require

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

Visual Studio Code underlines require and module keywords in my `.js` files which I run with Node. How to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Visual studio code is written in TypeScript you need to download type definitions for nodejs. To do this click on the text (require/ module) which is underlined. Now it would show a yellow bulb.

[image]

Now click on that yellow bulb. A menu should open , select `Download type definition for node.d.ts`. Done visual studio code will download the type files for you.

[image]

Now a `typings` folder will display in your project folder , remember to add that in your `.gitignore` file to avoid unnecessary file commit to your git repo

Comment: Thanks mate, I did not see the yellow bulb on click, but I ended up doing npm install -g tsd; tsd query node --action install

Comment: Yes you have to select the text for that. Also don't forget to up vote if you found it helpful, cheers :)

Comment: yeah no I selected text it does not come up. And I was wrong, I didn't see the underline after I've restarted but it came back a few sec afterwards, despite having node.d.ts in typings.

Comment: All code that is related to node core will be defined in ```node.d.ts``` Are you using visual studio code latest version?. Type definition is downloaded automatically by the visual studio code. you don't have to download it by your self.

Comment: it is, I think it is eslint problem rather than Visual Studio Code

Comment: Are you using eslint plugins for vscode?

In that case you might want to add ``` env: {node: true}```
to your eslintrc file

Comment: yep just did that and it works. Also I removed the node.d.ts and it works fine without it. cheers

Comment: I suggest do not remove the node.d.ts downloaded by your vs-code.

Comment: I think in the newer version it is embedded by default